# Search by id in Administrate Gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, rubygems, administrate

By default Administrate Gem gives us a feature where we can search record by name. But now I am trying to search record by ID in search bar of admin Dashboard, like this

```
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
  id: Field::Number,
  name: Field::String,
}.freeze
```

But I am not able to search records by its ID, I try this but didn't work

```
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
  id: Field::Number.with_options(searchable: true),
  name: Field::String,
}.freeze
```

I am expecting to serach records by two things, like ID and Name also

Answer (score 0):

In administrate gem give by default with_options(searchable :true or false) it is only for associated things for example(have a two models with name of user and employee with has_one association to search the employee thing in user page with_options(searchable: true) will work) you have search by id in admin dashboard use this code in your admin controller

```
def index
  authorize_resource(resource_class)
  search_term = params[:search].to_s.strip
  resources = filter_resources(scoped_resource, search_term: search_term)
  resources = apply_collection_includes(resources)
  resources = order.apply(resources)
  resources = resources.page(params[:_page]).per(records_per_page)
  page = Administrate::Page::Collection.new(dashboard, order: order)

  render locals: {
    resources: resources,
    search_term: search_term,
    page: page,
    show_search_bar: show_search_bar?,
  }
end

def filter_resources(resources, search_term:)
  Administrate::Search.new(
    resources,
    dashboard,
    search_term,
  ).run
 if search_term.present?
    resources.where(id: search_term)
  else
    resources.all
  end
end
```